# How to avoid force close when read null value

Tags: java, android, hwpf

I write simple android application to read document properties with Apache.POI,
but when it try to read document with null properties it will force close..

for example I use getDocumentSummaryInformation() then use getCompany()..
but when the document properties doesn't have any value in field Company then it will force closed.

How to handle this problem?
Sorry for my poor english and thank you for your attention.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.*;
import org.apache.poi.hpsf.DocumentSummaryInformation;
import org.apache.poi.hpsf.SummaryInformation;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.*;
import java.io.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getInit();

        cata = "";
        compa = "";

        readMyDocument(fileName);

        try {

                category.setText(cata);
            company.setText(compa);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            category.setText("Unknown Category");
            company.setText("Unknown Company");

        }

}



String fileName = "/sdcard/Test.doc";
public static String cata, compa;

public static void readMyDocument(String fileName){
    POIFSFileSystem fs = null;


    try {
        fs = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream(fileName));
        HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(fs);

        /** Read the document summary**/
        readDocumentSummary(doc);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }       
}   



public static MainActivity readDocumentSummary(HWPFDocument doc) {
    DocumentSummaryInformation summaryInfo=doc.getDocumentSummaryInformation();
    SummaryInformation summaryInfo2=doc.getSummaryInformation();

    MainActivity adata = new MainActivity();

        try{
        String category = summaryInfo2.getAuthor();
        adata.cata = category;
        }catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error occurred!, Error = "+e.toString());

        }

        try{
            String company = summaryInfo.getCompany();
            adata.compa = company;
            }catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error occurred!, Error = "+e.toString());

            }

    return adata;


}

TextView category;
TextView company;

public void getInit() {

    category = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.category);
    company = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.company);

}
}
```

Log:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument.filesystem
at org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument.<init>(HWPFDocument.java:218)
at org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument.<init>(HWPFDocument.java:158)
at com.ajs.metaxdc.MainActivity.readMyDocument(MainActivity.java:155)
at com.ajs.metaxdc.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:87)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:876)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:634)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Force finishing activity com.ajs.metaxdc/.MainActivity
```

Comment: Add your code which you tryied

Comment: put your code int try{}catch(exception){} block

Comment: This hot topic may help you solve the problem.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271526/avoiding-null-statements-in-java

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read Excel cell having null values too in Java...?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3132732/how-to-read-excel-cell-having-null-values-too-in-java)

Comment: thank you for replying, I have put my code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just leave hwpf function and use hpsf instead.. Because no one can help find solution to null value in hwpf property field.
Thank you for all people who tried to help me

Answer (score 0):

```
// Try this one
try{
    // write your code here
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code must be encountering NullPointerException. So you need to encapsulate your code in try/catch block. Catching an exception will allow you to do some corrective action if required in catch block. Also your code can continue executing Something like this:

```
try {
// read doc properties here
}catch(NullPointerException npe) {

}
```

Generally it is good to check to whether the object is null before calling methods on that to avoid NullPointerException.  So other way around could be:

```
if(yourDocObj == null) {
//don't call get methods on yourDocObj
} else {
//call get methods on yourDocObj
}
```

Comment: Do you have another suggestion? because it still force close even after I put code to let the textview blank in NullpointerException block (this try_catch replace if_else method for getCompany and getAuthor)

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid force close or some Exception by writing code between `Try-Catch` blocks

Try with following code.

```
try {
    // your code where force close occurs.
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Error Message : " + e.getMessage());
}
```

While to write exception in file Check this

- [Android Writing Logs to text File](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1756296/1160282)

Comment: Thank you for replying..
Can I write those error log to some file from android device then read it like general text file?

Answer (score 0):

Just simply use `Try and Catch` block, this way you will be able to handle the `NPE` exception in the Catch block.

Sample code;

```
try
{
 //Your functionality
 ....
}

Catch(Exception e)
{
 //Handle the Null Pointer Exception here.
 Log.e("YOUR_ACTIVITY_NAME", "Error occurred!, Error = "+e.toString());
....
}
```

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you for replying..
Do you have suggestion for me what to do in exception block?

Comment: Umm, i think you should use `Logs` in your catch block and modify your code according to the Error Logs that you receive in the Catch block.

Comment: Please check the edited answer too, you will be able to see all the Logs in your `LogCat` at the time of code execution.

Comment: Thank you, I get error log from my device.. But still cannot figure anything to solve this error

Comment: Please post the complete code of `MainActivity.java` file, then we will be able to solve your problem.

Comment: that is all I have., I only added "import" section